# Row by row computation

Tags: r

I have started learning R.

Need your help on how to do this computation in loop:

```
C1    C2     C3   
A     5      10   
A     4       6
B     2       3
B     8       9
```

I would like the output as

```
C1    C2         C3     C4(c2*c3)
A     5          10     50
A     4+50=54     6      54*6= 324
B     2           3      6
B     8+6=14      9      14*9 = 126
```

For each distinct value in column C1 the value calculated at C4 should be added to the new row value at C2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Loop ;-):

```
d <- read.table(text = "C1    C2     C3   
A     5      10   
A     4       6
B     2       3
B     8       9", header = TRUE)

my_calc <- function(d) {
  d[, 4] <- d[, 2] * d[, 3]
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(d) - 1)) {
    d[i+1, 2] <- d[i, 4] + d[i+1, 2]
    d[i+1, 4] <- d[i+1, 2] * d[i+1, 3]
  }
  d
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$C1), my_calc))

#C1 C2 C3  V4
#A.1  A  5 10  50
#A.2  A 54  6 324
#B.3  B  2  3   6
#B.4  B 14  9 126
```

Answer (score 6):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(C1) %>%
 mutate(C4 = (C2 + lag(C2 * C3, default = 0)) * C3,
        C2 = C2 + lag(C2 * C3, default = 0))


  C1       C2    C3    C4
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 A         5    10    50
2 A        54     6   324
3 B         2     3     6
4 B        14     9   126
```

Or using `data.table` (by @markus):

```
setDT(df)[, `:=`(C4 = (C2 + shift(C2 * C3, fill = 0)) * C3,
                 C2 = C2 + shift(C4, fill = 0)), by = C1]
```

Comment: you might want to add `mutate(C2_bis = C2 +lag(C4, default = 0) )` to have the C2 column as described in the desired output

Comment: @Carles Sans Fuentes I rejected your edit here as you are significantly changing the answer. You are also deleting (why??) the data.table solution

Comment: @Sotos I did the edit without getting to see data.table edition. I just wanted to fix the column C2 that was wrong and the result. Nothing else.

Comment: @CarlesSansFuentes No problem :). I was just letting you know based on the site's rules

Answer (score 0):

This loop should do the trick:

```
df = data.frame(C1=LETTERS[c(1,1,2,2)],C2=c(5,4,2,8),C3=c(10,6,3,9),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$C4=rep(0,nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (i!=1){
    if (df$C1[i]==df$C1[i-1]){
    df$C2[i]=df$C2[i]+df$C4[i-1]
    }
  }
  df$C4[i] = df$C2[i]*df$C3[i]
}

  C1 C2 C3  C4
1  A  5 10  50
2  A 54  6 324
3  B  2  3   6
4  B 14  9 126
```